# Minidump reading help for BSOD

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, crash, bsod, bluetooth

I've been having BSOD over the past few days. Nothing intentionally installed - apart from regular updates.

BSOD appears to be related to wifi/network/bluetooth activity. Started to happen when BT mouse on laptop stopped working, went to pair in PC & Devices/Bluetooth and it BSOD on trying to open Bluetooth pairng dialog with message:

```
PAGE_FAULT_IN_NON_PAGED_AREA (vuhub.sys)
```

Next time mouse stopped working and I didn't try to pair and after about 3-7 minutes it BSODs itself.

So went to Dell support, downloaded latest wifi/bt drivers and installed but with same BSOD results.

Tried removing all BT and Network devices, rebooting and re-installing network and wifi/BT drivers and still getting the same result.

Looked at minidump (pasted minidump analysis results below message) with dump viewer but not making much sense to me. Indicated that problem was with

Would appreciate some help if anyone can read dumps to assist in trying to figure out where the conflict is happening.

Also noticed that wifi speed test is down by 75% on upload and download when using wifi, but not when hard wired to router. Tested wifi speed test on another Win8.1 PC connected to the same router and wifi speed is performing at max. So router doesn't appear to be problem, although rebooted it anyway - without any change to my wifi speed.

System: Dell Laptop XPS 15
O/S: Win 8.1
Network driver: Killer Wireless
BT/Wifi: Atheros

### OSROnline Analysis Results

```
Crash Dump Analysis provided by OSR Open Systems Resources, Inc. (http://www.osr.com)
Online Crash Dump Analysis Service
See http://www.osronline.com for more information
Windows 8 Kernel Version 9600 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Built by: 9600.17041.amd64fre.winblue_gdr.140305-1710
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`8d803000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`8dacd2d0
Debug session time: Thu Apr 17 03:48:51.838 2014 (UTC - 4:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 1:16:47.690
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA (50)
Invalid system memory was referenced.  This cannot be protected by try-except,
it must be protected by a Probe.  Typically the address is just plain bad or it
is pointing at freed memory.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffe00108674ff8, memory referenced.
Arg2: 0000000000000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation.
Arg3: fffff8016369c0ab, If non-zero, the instruction address which referenced the bad memory
    address.
Arg4: 0000000000000000, (reserved)

Debugging Details:
------------------


Could not read faulting driver name
TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\modclass.ini, error 2

READ_ADDRESS: fffff8018dabace0: Unable to get special pool info
fffff8018dabace0: Unable to get special pool info
unable to get nt!MmNonPagedPoolStart
unable to get nt!MmSizeOfNonPagedPoolInBytes
 ffffe00108674ff8 

FAULTING_IP: 
vuhub+80ab
fffff801`6369c0ab 4c8b140a        mov     r10,qword ptr [rdx+rcx]

MM_INTERNAL_CODE:  0

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  AV

PROCESS_NAME:  UsbService64.e

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

TRAP_FRAME:  ffffd0017fca25d0 -- (.trap 0xffffd0017fca25d0)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=6853695602ae0000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=ffffe00108c2da10
rdx=ffffffffffa475e8 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff8016369c0ab rsp=ffffd0017fca2768 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=000000000000b430  r9=0000000000000351 r10=1a421bcfc82056cd
r11=ffffe00108c27000 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na pe nc
vuhub+0x80ab:
fffff801`6369c0ab 4c8b140a        mov     r10,qword ptr [rdx+rcx] ds:ffffe001`08674ff8=????????????????
Resetting default scope

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8018d9880e7 to fffff8018d956fa0

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd001`7fca23e8 fffff801`8d9880e7 : 00000000`00000050 ffffe001`08674ff8 00000000`00000000 ffffd001`7fca25d0 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffd001`7fca23f0 fffff801`8d86a9c9 : 00000000`00000000 ffffe001`02157880 ffffd001`7fca25d0 00000000`00000000 : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x20c37
ffffd001`7fca2490 fffff801`8d96122f : 00000000`00000000 ffffe001`03288e78 ffffe000`f4c6ab00 ffffd001`7fca25d0 : nt!MmAccessFault+0x7a9
ffffd001`7fca25d0 fffff801`6369c0ab : fffff801`6369af74 ffffd001`7fca2819 fffff801`630ad7f5 00000000`00000002 : nt!KiPageFault+0x12f
ffffd001`7fca2768 fffff801`6369af74 : ffffd001`7fca2819 fffff801`630ad7f5 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 : vuhub+0x80ab
ffffd001`7fca2770 ffffd001`7fca2819 : fffff801`630ad7f5 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 ffffe001`02157880 : vuhub+0x6f74
ffffd001`7fca2778 fffff801`630ad7f5 : 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 ffffe001`02157880 fffff801`8d959e36 : 0xffffd001`7fca2819
ffffd001`7fca2780 fffff801`8dbff8f2 : 00000000`00000000 ffffd001`7fca2b80 ffffe001`01efde10 00000000`00000001 : afd!AfdPoll64+0x66b
ffffd001`7fca2880 fffff801`8dc001c6 : 00000000`00000000 0000000c`001f0003 00000000`00000000 00000000`013dfd00 : nt!IopXxxControlFile+0x8d2
ffffd001`7fca2a20 fffff801`8d9627b3 : 00000000`00000000 ffffd001`7fca2ad8 00000000`00000000 fffff801`00000001 : nt!NtDeviceIoControlFile+0x56
ffffd001`7fca2a90 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
vuhub+80ab
fffff801`6369c0ab 4c8b140a        mov     r10,qword ptr [rdx+rcx]

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  4

SYMBOL_NAME:  vuhub+80ab

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: vuhub

IMAGE_NAME:  vuhub.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  473db7c1

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_AV_vuhub+80ab

BUCKET_ID:  X64_AV_vuhub+80ab

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

### BlueScreen Viewer Output

```
Dump File         : 041714-16937-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 17/04/2014 08:48:51
Bug Check String  : PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
Bug Check Code    : 0x00000050
Parameter 1       : ffffe001`08674ff8
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 3       : fffff801`6369c0ab
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+153fa0
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.3.9600.17041 (winblue_gdr.140305-1710)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+153fa0
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\041714-16937-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 9600
Dump File Size    : 323,856
Dump File Time    : 17/04/2014 08:50:17
==================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](http://sysnative.com/drivers/driver.php?id=vuhub.sys), vuhub.sys is the `Eltima Software USB to Ethernet Connector Driver`. Try to [update the driver/software](http://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-ethernet/).

Comment: Hi magicandre1981t, thanks for comment. Had looked at Eltima site but they send back to vendor site I.e. Dell and that file copied and updated already. Thx for response.